# How to convert this sql in criteria hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, criteria

This is my sql

```
SELECT *
FROM smt_aut.menu M
  JOIN smt_aut.tela T ON M.id_menu = T.id_menu
  JOIN smt_aut.tela_usuario TU ON T.id_tela = TU.id_tela
  WHERE TU.id_usuario = 1;
```

---

I tried this here but not gotta get result

---

```
    DetachedCriteria subQueryTU = DetachedCriteria.forClass( TelaUsuario.class, TelaUsuario_.nameQuery );
    subQueryTU.add( Restrictions.eq( TelaUsuario_.nameQuery + "." + TelaUsuario_.tela + "." + Tela_.idTela, Tela_.nameQuery + "." + Tela_.idTela ) );
    subQueryTU.add( Restrictions.eq( TelaUsuario_.nameQuery + "." + TelaUsuario_.usuario + "." + Usuario_.idUsuario, idUsuario ) );
    subQueryTU.setProjection( Projections.property( TelaUsuario_.idTelaUsuario ) );

    DetachedCriteria subQueryT = DetachedCriteria.forClass( Tela.class, Tela_.nameQuery );
    subQueryT.add( Restrictions.eqProperty( Tela_.nameQuery + "." + Tela_.menu + "." + Menu_.idMenu, Menu_.nameQuery + "." + Menu_.idMenu ) );
    subQueryT.setProjection( Projections.property( Tela_.idTela ) );

    subQueryT.add( Subqueries.exists( subQueryTU ) );

    Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria( Menu.class, Menu_.nameQuery );

    criteria.add( Subqueries.exists( subQueryT ) );

    return criteria.list();
```

---

I want find all menus when user 1 has access, ie return all menus where there  the User has access

Comment: have you this tables mapped?

Comment: Yes, all the tables are mapped!

Comment: Can you post your maps from your classes? Also, do you want to search `id_usuario` in `menu` ??